# Showing a certain series equals a certain trig function in complex analysis

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, trigonometry

I was reading a a complex analysis proof that was showing that for a fixed $\alpha$ s.t. $Im(\alpha)>0$ we have

$\sum \limits_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\alpha +n)^2}=(-4\pi^2)\sum \limits_{m=1}^{\infty} m e^{2\pi i m\alpha}$.

I understood this proof.  However, I need help with two other related statements.  First, the proof notes at the end this means that the series above on the left equals $\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi\alpha)}$.  In other words I am suppose to see that the one on the right above is equal to $\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi\alpha)}$.  I don't know the correct identities to show this so I would appreciate if someone would explain that.  Also, after the proof there is sort of a food for thought question that asks the reader if this identity was true for all complex numbers other than integers.  This seems valid but I would appreciate if someone would let me know that as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $\operatorname{Im} \alpha > 0$, we have $\lvert e^{2\pi i\alpha}\rvert = e^{-2\pi \operatorname{Im}\alpha} < 1$, so the series is basically a differentiated geometric series,

$$\sum_{m=1}^\infty m\cdot x^m = x\sum_{m=1}^\infty mx^{m-1} = x\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right) = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}.$$

Inserting $x = e^{2\pi i\alpha}$, we obtain

$$-4\pi^2 \sum_{m=1}^\infty me^{2\pi im\alpha} = \frac{-4\pi^2e^{2\pi i\alpha}}{(1- e^{2\pi i\alpha})^2},$$

moving the $e^{2\pi i\alpha}$ to the denominator, we then obtain

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(\alpha+n)^2} =\frac{-4\pi^2}{(e^{\pi i \alpha} - e^{-\pi i\alpha})^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2 \pi\alpha}.$$

Since the sum on the left hand side converges locally uniformly for $\alpha \notin \mathbb{Z}$, it defines a holomorphic function there. By the identity theorem, that holomorphic function is $\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2 \pi\alpha}$ on all of $\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$.